# I want to find a css that div automatically occupy the rest of the horizontal dimension

Tags: html, css

If you have two child divs in the parent div, and one of the child divs occupies the width of a particular value, i want to find a css that the other child div automatically occupy the rest of the horizontal dimension.

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
a {
  text-decoration:none;
}
li {
  list-style:none;
}
img {
  height:100%;
  border:0;
}
body,html {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
body {
  background-color:#161716;
  padding:2%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
#container {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:aquamarine;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
#scroll {
  width:2%;
  height:20%;
  margin-right:1%;
  background-color:burlywood;
}
#container_in {
  width: calc(100% - 26%);
  height:100%;
  margin-left:1%;
  margin-right:1%;
  background-color:deepskyblue;
}
#side {
  width:20%;
  height:100%;
  margin-left:1%;
  background-color:bisque;
}
#header {
  width:100%;
  height:15%;
}
header {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:darkviolet;
}
#logo {
  width:fit-content;
  height:100%;
  background-color:azure;
}

#logo a {
  width:fit-content;
  height:100%;
}
#navi {
  display:table-cell;
  width:auto;
  height:100%;
  background-color:navajowhite;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <link href="css/index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="scroll">
      </div> <!-- scroll end -->
      <div id="container_in">
        <div id="header">
          <header>
            <div id="logo">
              <a href="#">
                <img src="img/logo.jpg">
              </a>
            </div> <!-- logo end -->        
            <div id="navi">
              <nav>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
            </div> <!-- navi end -->
          </header>
        </div> <!-- header end -->
      </div> <!-- container_in end -->
      <div id="side">

      </div> <!-- side end -->
    </div> <!-- container end -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Once the entire structure is like the code above.

My question is the `div#header` section.

The `div#header header` is a child element of the `div#header`.

The `div#header header` contains two child div.

The parent area(`div#header header`) contains `#logo` and `#navi`.

The width of the `#logo` area is given as `width: fit-content;` to match the image size of the `#logo` child area.

Then the other child #navi can not use the same method as `width: calc (100% - 10px)` without knowing the width value of the #logo child.

I would like to use css only so that the rest of the `#logo` area in the div # header header area is automatically occupied by `#navi`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it simple with `flex` property

add `flex:1` to the div you want to give all the remaining space

```
#container_in{
  flex:1;
}
```

Minimal coded working snippet here:

```css
#container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
#container div{
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
#container_in{
  flex:1;
  background: blue;
}
#scroll{
  background: red;
}
#side{
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="scroll">scroll</div>
  <div id="container_in">It will occupy remaining space</div>
  <div id="side"> side</div>
</div>
```

Working **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dhbcfyts/)** here